# How can I store a list of dataframe references for use later?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to persist a collection of Spark dataframe object references, so that I can iterate over the collection later on. Specifically I'm trying dynamically uncache the dataframes of which I persisted in my code.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class CacheCatalogue() 
{
  val CachedDataFrames = mutable.ArrayBuffer[DataFrame]()

  def AddToCache(dataFrame:DataFrame) 
  {
     dataFrame.cache
     CachedDataFrames += dataFrame
  }

}

val catalogue = new CacheCatalogue()
```

However when I perform any kind of operation on a dataframe that has been passed to the AddToCache() function, "I'm getting Task not serializable" exceptions

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below and see.

```
 val catalogue = new CacheCatalogue() with Serializable
```